# Heroku with sinatra does not have RAILS_ROOT or Rail.root

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sinatra

I'm trying to upload file to amazon s3 and apparently I have to write to a temp file first then upload that file. But I cannot figure it out how to do that with Sinatra and heroku since it cannot find "#{RAILS_ROOT}" or #{Rail.root} how do I upload temp file to sinatra with heroku.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming you have read through Heroku's docs for [Uploading to S3](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3). The temp directory path on Heroku is `./tmp`. If you are running Sinatra, Heroku likely does not create the environment variables related to Rails (although it may, I'm not sure). [Here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) is more info on Heroku's file system.

EDIT: In Sinatra, you can get the root directory via `settings.root`, similar to `RAILS_ROOT`.